# How to keep the language across different pages of a localized site?

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I'm developing a basic website using PHP's built-in gettex support. I don't want to use any components of external libraries for different reasons; first because I want to practice the techniques related to gettex, second because the site is small enough not to demand anything other than vanilla php, third for performance. The issue I'm facing now is related to navigating the site in the languages I have already localized.

I've started out by setting up the needed directory structure:

```
locales/
    - pt_BR/
        - LC_MESSAGES
            messages.mo
            messages.po
    - es_ES/
    - ru/
```

Then included a file with the code below at the top of each page:

```
<?php
// use sessions
session_start();

// get language preference
if (isset($_GET["lang"])) {
    $language = $_GET["lang"];
}
elseif (isset($_SESSION["lang"])) {
    $language  = $_SESSION["lang"];
}
else {
    $language = "en_US";
}

// save language preference for future page requests
$language = $_SESSION["Language"];

$folder = "locale";
$domain = "messages";
$encoding = "UTF-8";

putenv("LANG=" . $language);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

bindtextdomain($domain, $folder);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $encoding);

textdomain($domain);
```

After setting up the code I added a simple rule to my `.htaccess` not to use a query string, but simple locale codes instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+/)?pt-br/? ?lang=pt_BR
```

For the home page at the server root directory it worked as expected. If I type a url like *mysite.test* it renders everything in English and if I switch to *mysite.test/pt-br* I get everything in Brazilian Portuguese. My trouble is: how can I have the other pages in the site to keep this pattern? If I enter *mysite.test/pt-br/about*, for instance, I get the same home page in Brazilian Portuguese, not the *About* (equally previously localized) page.

In my understanding that happens because the server looks for the file **about.php** inside the directory **pt-br** that, in fact, doesn't exist, then it resorts back to the rewrite rule, but... I don't really think this is the case and am wondering how the whole thing is done, that is, building a structure where URLs are such as:

```
mysite.test/pt-br/about
mysite.test/es/about
mysite.test/ru/about
```

And the same for any other page.

I haven't found anything precise enough around other than instructions on how to set up the directory structure for gettex to work and using sections to keep the language choice, but I'm not sure on the implementation, so any help to find material on that would be really appreciated.

Comment: `$language  = $_SESSION["lang"];` / `$_SESSION["Language"]  = $language;`

Comment: +1 Even though this is subject to be closed due to typo only, you've earned to get much rep in order to investing the effort forming a proper question on SO! Well done!

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, the odd thing about the typo you mentioned above is that as soon as I fixed it in my code the expected output I described when entering an url such as *mysite.test/pt-br* stopped working. I get the English version of the page only.

Comment: Please update the question accordingly. What is the value of `$language`?

Comment: `$folder = "locale";` but you show a structure `locales/...`